# Get an Element by his attributes

Tags: java, object, arraylist, attributes

**What I need** : Getting an Element
I have created two objects from a class which has 2 attributes: id and name.
After I create an object, I set it's ID and add the object to an ArrayList:

```
Variable variable1 = new Variable();
variable1.setID(1);
Variable variable2 = new Variable();
variable1.setID(2);
ArrayList<Variable> varList = new ArrayList<Variable>(); 
varList.add(variable1);
varList.add(variable2);
```

Then in my code I want to get the Element which has Id == 1 but I didn't find a method that can return me the Object by giving it the Object attribute.

Is there a method like this : Object o = getObjectByAttribute(Object.id==1) ?

Comment: @BijuCD  _"Adding java8 tag for making this question a java8 relevant question"_ Why you add the java-8 tag? The OP didn't precise that he's using java 8 or that he wants a java 8 answer... If you want to provide a java 8 one, feel free to add it and precise it in your answer, but don't edit question's tag for that. Rolling back your edit.

Comment: Yes it is not about java8 , it is about the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `Collections.binarySearch()` and a custom `Comparator`

[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T))

**EDIT:** code snippet:

```
Comparator<Variable> comparator = new Comparator<Variable>() {
    public int compare(Variable o1, Variable o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.getID(), o2.getID());
    }
};
Collections.sort(varList, comparator);
Variable key = new Variable();
key.setID(1);
int index = Collections.binarySearch(varList, key, comparator);
```

Comment: remember to `sort` the collection before you run `binarySearch`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java8, filters(in lambda expression) is a good option.

```
Stream<Variable> outputList = varList.stream().filter(val -> val.getId() ==1);
```

outputList will contain only Variable objects with Id 1. First element can be taken from that list if it is not empty.

Ref: 
http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/

Comment: You could at least modify a bit your answer so that it applies with the OP use case... and make it complete, i.e getting the correct `Variable` instance at the end. It's so incomplete...

Comment: @user2336315 modified. Thanks.

Comment: Downvote removed, although it's a stream not a list... You should also show how to get this element from the list.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method like this : Object o =
>   getObjectByAttribute(Object.id==1) ?

No, but it's easy to create one. Create an interface `Function` that from an Object of type T give a property of type U.

```
interface Function<T, U> {
    U apply(T t);
}
```

Then the method:

```
public static <T, U> T getObjectByAttribute(List<T> objects, Function<T, U> fromAttribute, U attributeResearched) {
    for(T obj : objects) {
        if(fromAttribute.apply(obj).equals(attributeResearched)) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and how to call it:

```
Variable v = getObjectByAttribute(varList, new Function<Variable, Integer>() {
                       @Override
                       public Integer apply(Variable variable) {
                            return variable.id;
                       }
              }, 1);
```